# My Create storage is disabled when I am trying persisting files in Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

I need to create storage in order to persist files in Azure Cloud Shell.
I was told only North Europe is available for my azure resource group.
However, "Create storage" is disabled as shown below even when there is an available storage account.
[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To: Sarques Many thanks for your kind edits.

Comment: Looks you did not provide the name of file share https://i.stack.imgur.com/usZuY.png

Comment: The file share I created does not show up even when I choose "Use existing". Will "Create new" allow Azure to create a new file share for me?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you can have a try, it is not a big problem, right?

Comment: As shown in the screenshot, "Create storage" remains disabled when "Create new" is chosen. Selecting "Use existing" does not show the file share that I have already created.

Comment: Hi Joy Wang, Sorry I did not follow your advice earlier. In fact, I just worked around this issue by using existing file share. I entered an existing file share name instead of selecting from what has been listed.

Comment: So does it work now?

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, I wish I could but I should not be able to to accept it as an answer due to my low stackoverflow reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue, you need to select the file share from what has been listed from `Use existing` or `Create new`, then it will work.

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0EM5.png shows what are available to me. Is there a button for me to click?

Comment: @gugu Just click this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK3Fv.png